# Telerik package upgrade to 2021 is not updating jQuery files from folder Scripts/Kendo/2019.x.xxxx

Tags: telerik, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-asp.net-core

I used to upgrade telerik controls from telerik wizard appears in the telerik menu in visual studio(till vs2019 version). It used to created folder under scripts folder with named kendo/xxxx verison name. when upgrade this folder will be updated to latest version.
Now my application migrated to .net core and I upgraded telerik package from nuget to telerik.UI.for.Aspnet.core version=2021.2
But in my project scripts folder still kendo/2019.x.xx version jquery files avaiable and when I removed it it's showing kendo errors in project while loading UI

How can I upgrade to latest Jquery files in my project , it can replace 2019.x.xx folder with latest folder along with jquery files.